# Access string property in multiple methods of C#.Net Console Application

Tags: c#-4.0, properties, console-application, stringbuilder

How can i access a Property in Multiple methods of same class?

```
  class MainProgram
{
    List<string> logLines = new List<string>();
    private static void ParseTransmissionAction(string ActionChar)
    {
        logLines.Add(ActionChar);
    }
    private static void BeginProcessing(int i, string FileName)
    {
        logLines.Add(i + ")" + FileName + "...Processing...");
    }
    private static void CompletedParsingthisFile(string File, int Rows)
    {
        logLines.Add("Sucessfully Parsed \"" + File + "\" (" + Rows + ") Rows");
    }
}
```

Comment: I fail to see how your title, code, and tags are related. Care to explain what it is you're trying to do?

Comment: Other than the fact that this is crying for `string.Format()` I don't see what needs to be done here.

Comment: @minitech I am trying to write a log file. For each instance. I need to capture the message in each method and write it to a log file at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`logLines` in your program is not marked as `static`, and thus all your methods can't access it.

Change it to `static` or remove the `static` modifier on your methods.